# How can I make a ui text to blink fade in out?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

First I tried to get component material but the UI `text` don't have material so I tried to get component directly to the color component but I'm getting the following error :

> ArgumentException: GetComponent requires that the requested component 'Color' derives from MonoBehaviour or Component or is an interface.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class SaveGameMessage : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;
    public Text text;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        var textColor = text.GetComponent<Color>();
        textColor.a = (Mathf.Sin(Time.time * speed) + 1.0f) / 2.0f;
    }
}
```

**The updated code :**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class SaveGameMessage : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;
    public Text text;

    private Color textColor;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        textColor = text.color;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        textColor.a = (Mathf.Sin(Time.time * speed) + 1.0f) / 2.0f;
    }
}
```

**I also tried with `PingPong` :**

```
textColor.a = Mathf.PingPong(Time.time * speed, 1.0f);
```

but it's never blinking fade in out.

There is a `Canvas` set to Screen Space - Overlay and the `Text` is child of it :
If I change the alpha color of the Text in the editor it will make it transparent and back but with the script it's not working. The script is attached to the `Text`.

[image: Ui Text]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var textColor = text.GetComponent<Color>();
```

There is the error Doesnt exist the component color.

You need to access to the property Color in this way

```
var textColor = text.color;
```

```
void Update() 
{ 
   textColor.a = (Mathf.Sin(Time.time * speed) + 1.0f) / 2.0f;
   text.color = textColor; 
}
```

Comment: The error is gone but the text never blink. I updated my question with the current code.

Comment: You dont assign the new color to the text. Check ther i update the code